# Boostrap Responsive Design Grid Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building the front end of my website in bootstrap 4. I'd like one of my pages to be split into four background images each of which fills a column so that the columns stack responsively on mobile. As of now, I have the design below where I use the background-image attribute to fill each column. The images do not fill the whole column though.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="img img-profile-1">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="img img-profile-2" >

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="img img-profile-3" >

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <div class="img img-profile-4">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added the css below to the div within each column and got the full image to show but there is a strange scrolling issue and white space when I make the viewport smaller.

```
.img-profile-1 {
        background-image: url('../img/image.jpg') !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }
```

Any ideas how to get handle this responsive vs background image dilemma?
Thanks!

Comment: could you provide a working jsfiddle? at lease show us where you stuck~ thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add another `<div>` inside the `.col-md-3` in order to give it a background, instead you can just give that same `<div>` the class of `.img-profile-1` and so on.

Bootstrap 4 also adds a cool class to where it removes all white spaces between each `.col`, it is called `.no-gutters`. You can view that on the snip below.

```css
.img-profile-1,
.img-profile-3 {
        background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500/aaaaaa/000000');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 300px;
    }
    

.img-profile-2,
.img-profile-4 {
        background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500/000000/ffffff');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-3 img img-profile-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 img img-profile-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 img img-profile-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center img img-profile-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the width and height in your css for the div,  try adding class img-fluid to the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the fix**
If you add col-md-3 or any other column in bootstap it take right padding and left padding of 15px so that inner content will no cover full width. To cover full width we need to add another div with class row below the column so that inner content will be made to cover full width

**Fixed code is given below**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img img-profile-1">

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img img-profile-2" >
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img img-profile-3" >
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img img-profile-4">
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```